# Insert new DIV between two DIVs that have the same class or data-ident

Tags: javascript, jquery

Struggling with this one for a while now. My markup simplified:

```
<div class=row>
    <div class="testdiv" data-ident="1"></div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-ident="2"></div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-ident="3"></div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-ident="4"></div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-ident="5"></div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-ident="6"></div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-ident="7"></div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-ident="8"></div>
    <div class="testdiv" data-ident="9"></div>
</div>
```

I need to find a way to select all DIVs on document ready that:

1. has a class: testdiv & data-ident="XXX"
2. their next DIV also has the class name: testdiv & data-ident="YYY"

Then I need to insert/append a 4 new DIV`s between them, to group them, exactly the same as the following example:

```
<div class=row>
    <div class="NEW DIV 1"></div>
        <div class="testdiv" data-ident="1"></div>
        <div class="NEW DIV 2">
            <div class="testdiv" data-ident="2"></div>
            <div class="testdiv" data-ident="3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="testdiv" data-ident="4"></div>
        <div class="NEW DIV 3">
            <div class="testdiv" data-ident="5"></div>
            <div class="testdiv" data-ident="6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="testdiv" data-ident="7"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="NEW DIV 4">
        <div class="testdiv" data-ident="8"></div>
        <div class="testdiv" data-ident="9"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Since I can`t edit the plugin/source code, I need Java / jQuery to do this , but I don't know how to...

Comment: Do you need to get the divs by pairs? Like in your example, [2,3], [5,6], [8,9] and so on? Or could you for instance group [2,3,4], then [1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem using

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
   $( '[data-ident="XX"], [data-ident="YY"]' ).wrapAll( "<div class='NEW DIV'></div>" );
  }, 2000)
});
```

Comment: Hey could you explain your code a bit? Also, you shouldn't need the `setTimeout` I just tried it without it and works fine! Also, if you solved your problem, do mark your answer as accepted!

Comment: I'm not senior dev :) but without setTimeout it doesn't work for me.